# execute a script inside another script

Tags: linux, bash

I've a script like this:

```
/root/bin/script1.sh
```

putting this line inside .bashrc

```
/root/bin/script1.sh &
```

`script1.sh` does not run - the problem is &. Without "&" the script run perfectly

Comment: How can you tell it isn't running?

Comment: Hello, script1.sh is a long process.. so using ps I can see if does run or not.

Comment: And is it happy to run in the background normally (ie, from the shell)?

Comment: sure: I've already tested it obviously

Comment: Why do you want to put "a long process" into `~/.bashrc` of all things? This gets loaded with *every* connection...

Comment: exactly I need to run script after logon of root user

Comment: Every single time?

Comment: Every time root admin does the logon.

Comment: i run my long-running background scripts via `screen`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

command tested:

```
/root/bin/script1.sh & disown
```

(this line inside .bashrc)

Comment: doc for `disown` in `man bash`

Answer (score 2):

Try putting this into your `.bashrc`:

`( /root/bin/script1.sh & )`

This will execute your script inside a subshell.